# nautilus-clutterflow only works in "sudo-mode"

Tags: nautilus, clutterflow

could any body help?
Why is nautilus elementary's "clutterflow" only active when nautilus is started as "sudo nautilus"?

I ran "nautilus -q" and got this error: 
*"nautilus -q" generates an error... in ubuntu 11.04. Following error: (nautilus:3746): Unique-DBus-WARNING **: Error while sending message: Message did not receive a reply (timeout by message bus).*

Now, i ran the same command "sudo nautilus -q" and nothing happend. But running "nautilus &" without "-q" brings up the browser, but clutterflow won't work either.

Clutterflow only works with "sudo nautilus &" but i don't want to be surfing around in super user mode..., how can i resolve this?

Thanks for reading and please respond if you can !

Answer (score 2):

in **gconf-editor**

check "**show_clutter**"
and set "**clutter_test**" to **0**

ok, then 
**nautilus -q** and try **F4**

in my case, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

ALT + F2, enter: gconf-editor and then navigate to apps > nautilus > preferences and enable 'show_clutter'.
Restart Nautilus (nautilus -q).

Comment: thank man, Andrew i did that already quite a couple of times, but each time that box was checked, and clutterflow was turned on, the application simply crashed. After the crash, show_clutter check box is unchecked automatically. Well, i don't know if there actually lies the problem, but starting nautilus with sudo seem to be the only way the render clutterflow, well at least for now. But seriously, i won't like navigating my private folders and files in sudo mode...
Thanks anyway for responding !