# Clutterflow in nautilus elementary does nothing

Tags: nautilus-elementary, clutterflow

Ok try as I might I cannot get clutterflow to work in nautilus elementary, I have seen the posts about vblank such as [nautilus elementary coverflow not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8999/nautilus-elementary-coverflow-not-working) ~ I have also found out that it works while running under root as in this post [nautilus-clutterflow only works in "sudo-mode"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46126/nautilus-clutterflow-only-works-in-sudo-mode) I even tried the libpoppler route [Clutterflow not working on Nautilus Elementary](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41056/clutterflow-not-working-on-nautilus-elementary) but none of them work.  There is no black box where clutterflow is supposed to be, no nothing.  I press F4 and absolutely nothing happens.  The embedded terminal is fine however.  I even tried the gconf settings to show clutter and clutter test = 0 nothing works.  Thank you everyone for taking the time to try to help, it's appreciated.

Comment: Clutterflow seems to not be working anymore on 11.04, and when it does the icons it shows are corrupted so, it's of no use.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
**Alt+F2** (or in terminal) type 
**gconf-editor**

Then **Apps** -> **Nautilus** -> **Preferences**

check "**show_clutter**"
and set "**clutter_test**" to **0**

ok, then 
**nautilus -q** and try **F4**

in my case, it worked.